# Present/Past perfect with 'Recent'/'Yesterday'

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, time-reference

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. Recently they **have watched** a new film and now we are expecting their mind about it.
> 2. Recently they **had watched** a new film and now we are expecting their mind about it.
> 3. Recently they **watched** a new film and now we are expecting their mind about it.

It seems at least 1 and 3 both are correct and mean the same thing.

And what if we replace ‘Recently’ with ‘Yesterday’?
Present Perfect tense doesn’t use with ‘Yersterday’ but Past Perfect use as well.

> - Yesterday they **had watched** a new film and now we are expecting their mind about it.
> - Yesterday they **watched** a new film and now we are expecting their mind about it.

Comment: I don't see a real problem with any of the tenses. However, *we are expecting their mind* is strange and unidiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. Is 'we expect their mind' more natural? 
I thought that 'had watched' is discordant with 'now' unlike 'have watched'

Comment: No. If you're going to keep *mind* in some form, it would be something like *we are expecting **they will speak their mind** about it*. But that's still a bit odd. You could use *we are waiting (for / to hear) their thoughts*, *we are waiting (for / to hear) their opinion* or *we are waiting (for / to hear) their feedback*.

Comment: But I still have doubts about sentence **yesterday they had watched a film and now we are …** 
In general, it is not appropriate to use past perfect unless the context involves two identifiable time periods in the past. Reference to the most recent uses past, reference to the other uses past perfect. 
For example:
Past...Time A...Time B...Present.
 *They had watched a film yesterday before 9 pm and now we are ...* Here *yesterday before 9 pm*  referring to Time B; *had watched* is past perfect, referring to Time A, earlier than Time B. But
original sentense reffers is only past time B

Comment: There's no reason why tenses can't be combined. It just depends on *how* they are combined. In this case, it's fine. (As it is in many other pieces of writing.) For instance, you *shouldn't* say, "I went to the store before I will make dinner." It's not done because it doesn't make *sense*, not merely because it's mixing tenses.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the time-marker *Yesterday* is poorly combined with *had watched* because *yesterday* means time B without previouse time A. I have just started learning English and now I hope that similar senseless questions about tenses will disappear in the future tenses.
However, I have the last senseless question. Is there a normal context for the non-standart sentense *Yersterday I had seen what mother bought for him* or  tenses was not combine correctly in every way (by all means).